# Part acting as Identity

Tags: list-manipulation

I noticed that for example `a[[]]` will output `a`.
Is there any value we can give to `i` such that `a[[i]]` gives `a`.

Looking at the FullForm `Part[a]` the answer is probably no we can't go from `Part[a,i]` to `Part[a]`. ( I thought `Nothing` might help but it only works for lists and not for a Sequence. I guess I can make a Nothing-like object for sequences.)

Comment: You can use `Sequence[]` or `## &[]` as a vanishing argument for `i`.

Comment: @Sjoerd, thanks, wow I feel stupid now.

Comment: Depends what do you mean by "gives `a`", If `a = {1,2,4}`, then `a[[All]]` gives `a`.

Comment: @Kuba, yes that is true. But I meant something that works in general. And I think Sequence[] does work in general, right?

Comment: Compare `1[[]]` with `1[[All]]`. The two are slightly different for atoms without parts. It seems that `1[[]]` is slightly closer to what OP wanted.